# Maximal vs. Closed Patterns in Association Rule Mining

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

In frequent itemset generation of association rule mining, what is the fundamental difference between maximal & closed patterns itemsets. Can someone guide me a resource about them?

Answer (score 17):

From [this original source](https://www.a.kopo.com/wp/mes/?sid=9&lid=16):

> A closed pattern is a frequent pattern. So it meets the minimum
>   support criteria. In addition to that, all super-patterns of a closed
>   pattern are less frequent than the closed pattern.
>
> Let’s see some examples.
>
> Suppose, the minimum support count is 2. For the first example,
>   suppose there are a total of 3 items: a, b, c. Suppose a pattern ab
>   has support count of 2 and a pattern abc has support count of 2. Is
>   the pattern ab is a closed pattern? Pattern ab is a frequent pattern,
>   but it has a super-pattern that is NOT less frequent than ab.
>
> For the second example,
>
> suppose there are a total of 3 items: x, y, z. suppose a pattern xy
>   has support count of 3 and a pattern xyz has support count of 2. Is
>   the pattern xy is a closed pattern? Pattern xy is a frequent pattern
>   and also the only super-pattern xyz is less frequent than xy.
>
> Therefore, xy is a closed pattern.
>
> A max pattern is
>
> a frequent pattern. So it also meets the minimum support criteria like
>   closed pattern In addition, but unlike closed pattern, all
>   super-patterns of a max pattern are NOT frequent patterns.
>
> Let’s see some examples as well.
>
> Suppose, the minimum support count is 2. Like before, for the first
>   example, suppose there are a total of 3 items: a, b, c. Suppose a
>   pattern ab has support count of 3 and a pattern abc has support count
>   of 2. Is the pattern ab is a max pattern? Pattern ab is a frequent
>   pattern, but it has a super-pattern that is a frequent pattern as
>   well. So, pattern ab is NOT a max pattern.
>
> For the second example,
>
> suppose there are a total of 3 items: x, y, z. Suppose a pattern xy
>   has support count of 3 and a pattern xyz has support count of 1. Is
>   the pattern xy is a max pattern? Pattern xy is a frequent pattern and
>   also the only super-pattern xyz is NOT a frequent pattern. Therefore,
>   xy is a max pattern.

Comment: Hi, it appears that you copied this answer from [this site](https://www.a.kopo.com/wp/mes/?sid=9&lid=16) with no attribution. You're using someone else's work without giving the author credit. This amounts to plagiarism, and is not welcome on Stack Overflow. Remember to always add prominent attribution when using other sources. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for editing the answer by adding the source. Will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 5):

In frequent itemset mining:

> - A  maximal itemset is an itemset that has no superset that is frequent.
> - A closed itemset is an itemset that has no superset that has the same support.

Maximal itemsets are a subset of the set of closed itemsets, which are a subset of all frequent itemsets.

You can get implementations of closed and maximal itemset mining algorithms (FPMax, FPClosed, DCI_Closed, CHarm, etc.) with examples as part of the [SPMF data mining library](http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/). (I'm the author)

Answer (score 5):

In frequent itemset mining:

X is said to be a **max-pattern** if X is a frequent pattern and there exists no frequent super pattern Y (where Y is a super set of X). Max Patterns are lossy forms of compression as the underlying support information is lost.

On the other hand, X is said to be a **closed-pattern** if X is frequent and there exits no super pattern Y (where Y is a super set of X) with the same support as X. Closed Patterns are lossless forms of compression, as the support information is stored within the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

i think your question addresses maximal frequent itemset and closed frequent itemset.

The main difference between them are

@maximal frequent itemset does not provide the support count of their subsets.

@closed frequent itemset  preserves the support count of its itemset.

you can refer the following link for better understanding about association mining and maximal and closed frequent itemset.

http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~kumar/dmbook/ch6.pdf